# Are the members of Beck based on real life musicians?

Tags: beck

It's fairly well-known among Beck fans that Chiba, the lead vocalist of Beck, is based on Zack De La Rocha from Rage Against the Machine. However, the other characters don't seem to be obviously based on anyone famous to me. Are the other band members also based on or inspired by any famous musicians?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides Chiba, I'm only aware of the bassist, [Taira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck_%28manga%29#Characters), resembling RCHP's bassist, [Flea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flea_%28musician%29). They both often play shirtless on stage and share the bleached-blonde look.

> Beck's bassist, Taira is the second member recruited by Ryusuke. Although he can sometimes seem uncaring or apathetic, he is actually the most mature of the band members and often offers helpful advice. He usually performs shirtless, **much like the real-life person he is based on: Flea of the Red Hot Chili Peppers.** His main live bass is a white Music Man Stingray (a 1993-1996 model as identified from the type of bridge) with 3-band EQ and a trans bridge.

Flea is also known to use the [Music Man Stingray](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Man_StingRay).

[image]
[image]

The mangaka, [Harold Sakuishi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Sakuishi), is an RHCP fan and, according to WP, has claimed that Beck is partly inspired by the band. I don't know if this extends to other members of the band.

> Harold Sakuishi himself has admitted that the **band is inspired in part by the Red Hot Chili Peppers**. Sakuishi admits that they are his favorite band; their music, specifically the song "Under the Bridge", helped him through a difficult time in his life. **A one-shot manga also called Under the Bridge was written by Sakuishi and narrates his first meeting with the band.** This influence is widely seen in Beck, not only in the band's musical style, but also in the fact that **Taira heavily resembles a younger version of Flea, the Chili Peppers' own bassist**, both in looks (he is mostly seen playing shirtless and has his hair bleached blonde, as Flea used to have his own) and in playing style.